# Koma change font of TOC section entries

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I've got a strange problem.
I try to use the main monospace font for the whole TOC and the entries of it in the text. But for some reason it does not work for the section entries in the TOC. But it does for the sections itself. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{scrreprt}
     \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
     \usepackage{xltxtra}

    \setsansfont[
        Ligatures={TeX,Common%,Rare
            },
        RawFeature=+onum;+pnum,
        SmallCapsFont={Alegreya Sans SC}
    ]{Alegreya Sans}

    \setmonofont[
    Ligatures={TeX,Common%,Rare
    },
    RawFeature=+onum;+pnum,
    ]{Anonymous Pro}

    \setromanfont[
        Scale=MatchLowercase,
        Ligatures={TeX,Common%,Rare
            },
        RawFeature=+onum;+pnum,
        SmallCapsFont={Cormorant SC},
    BoldItalicFont={Cormorant Italic}
    ]{Cormorant}

    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\ttfamily}
    \addtokomafont{title}{\rmfamily}
    \addtokomafont{titlehead}{\rmfamily}
    \addtokomafont{subtitle}{\rmfamily}
    \addtokomafont{publishers}{\sffamily}
    \addtokomafont{date}{\sffamily}
    \addtokomafont{author}{\sffamily}

    \newcommand{\ProtM}{A Male}
    \newcommand{\ProtW}{Female}
    \newcommand{\ProtO}{Others}

    \newcommand{ \HE}[1]{\section{\ProtM: #1}}
    \newcommand{\SHE}[1]{\section{\ProtW: #1}}
    \newcommand{\THEY}[1]{\section{\ProtO: #1}}

    \title{\textsc{Maintitle in rm sc}}
    \subtitle{subtitle in rm}
    \author{My name in sf}
    \date{Place, \footnote{\today} in sf}
    \publishers{\XeLaTeX in sf}

    \newcommand{\blndtxt}{Here is a bit text \dots Is here a bit text? Is the text here just a bit? A bit text is here. Text is here a for a while. Isn't it?}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \HE{Hello world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
    \SHE{Hello world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
    \THEY{Hello world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
    \chapter{AnotherTest Chapter}
    \HE{Bye world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
    \SHE{Bye world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
    \THEY{Bye world}
    \blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the chapter level has own font elements for TOC entries and their page numbers. They use element `disposition`. So the chapter entries are monospaced.

To change only the font for the TOC entries of other section levels you can use in the preamble:

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\ttfamily}
```

But then the page numbers of the entries are not monospaced:

[image]

Note that I have used `libertine` because I do not have your fonts.

---

With KOMA-Script version 3.20 or newer you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the font of the entries and its page numbers

```
\newcommand*\tocentryformat[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}
\RedeclareSectionCommands
  [
    tocentryformat=\tocentryformat,
    tocpagenumberformat=\tocentryformat
  ]
  {section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{libertine}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\ttfamily}
\addtokomafont{title}{\rmfamily\scshape}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{titlehead}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{subtitle}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{publishers}{\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{date}{\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{author}{\sffamily}

\newcommand*\tocentryformat[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}
\RedeclareSectionCommands
  [
    tocentryformat=\tocentryformat,
    tocpagenumberformat=\tocentryformat
  ]
  {section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}


\newcommand{\ProtM}{A Male}
\newcommand{\ProtW}{Female}
\newcommand{\ProtO}{Others}

\newcommand{ \HE}[1]{\section{\ProtM: #1}}
\newcommand{\SHE}[1]{\section{\ProtW: #1}}
\newcommand{\THEY}[1]{\section{\ProtO: #1}}

\title{Maintitle in rm sc}% <- changed
\subtitle{subtitle in rm}
\author{My name in sf}
\date{Place, \footnote{\today} in sf}
\publishers{\XeLaTeX in sf}

\newcommand{\blndtxt}{%
  Here is a bit text \dots Is here a bit text?
  Is the text here just a bit?
  A bit text is here. Text is here a for a while. Isn't it?%
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\HE{Hello world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\SHE{Hello world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\THEY{Hello world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\chapter{AnotherTest Chapter}
\HE{Bye world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\SHE{Bye world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\THEY{Bye world}
\blndtxt\blndtxt\blndtxt
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only for short toc. If it is langer than one page no pagebreak is used.

Comment: @Dirk Which KOMA-Script version do you use? Please ask a new question including a MWE showing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](http://www.golatex.de/aenderung-der-schriftarten-im-koma-script-im-toc-t2013.html).

Just replace your `\tableofcontents` with `{\renewcommand*\normalfont{\usekomafont{disposition}}\normalfont\tableofcontents}`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get the word "Inhaltsverzeichnis" in boldface like all other chapters or sections, respectively?