# KOMA cannot change font in ToC for section

Tags: xetex, koma-script

I successfully changed the font for the chapters, sections etc. and for the chapterentry in ToC, but it doesn't change the font for sectionentry. How can I set all elements in the ToC to have the same font?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{JVAthesis}[]
\LoadClass[fontsize=12pt, a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, twoside=off, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

    \RequirePackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing

    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}%{Calibri}
    \newfontfamily{\EXO}{Exo 2}

    \setkomafont{disposition}{\EXO}
    \setkomafont{chapterentry}{\EXO}
    \setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\EXO}

    \setkomafont{pagenumber}{\EXO}
    \renewcommand{\headfont}{\EXO}

     \setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\huge\scshape\color{BZLblue}\EXO}
     \setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\color{BZLblue}\EXO}
     \setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\scshape\color{BZLblue}\EXO}

     ...
```

However, setting the sectionentry is not possible because the class is based on scrbook. Result looks like this
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360135/koma-change-font-of-toc-section-entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition},
  tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, twoside=off, numbers=noenddot,headlines=1.4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{BZLblue}{blue!70!black}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily{\EXO}{Exo 2}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\EXO}

\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\usekomafont{disposition}}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\usekomafont{disposition}}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\color{BZLblue}}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\color{BZLblue}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\color{BZLblue}}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition},
  tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly fine!